# React Router 4 issue passing props, only location is being passed

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

this is a simplified version of what i'm having issues with

I'm trying to pass some properties to my component (SomeComponent), but only location (routerProps) is being passed

```
<Router>
  <Switch>
    <Route
      exact
      path="/"
      render={routerProps => (
        <SomeComponent
          test="XXX"
          collections={this.props}
          {...routerProps}
        />
      )}
    />

    <Route exact strict path="/:id" component={SomeComponent2} />
    <Route
      render={() => <SiteError error="404" status="404" />}
    />
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

When SomeComponent loads, only the location prop (routerProps) is available, test and collections are not there (no errors either)

any ideas

thx

Comment: Does this simplified version work? I recreated your simplified version but it works. I'm guessing this simplified version doesn't include your stumbling point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use my component, it will act like the Route component but it will pass the props on Route to the child component. I copied it from somewhere here on Stackoverflow, but i forgot from where.

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import Route from "react-router-dom/Route";

const renderMergedProps = (component, ...rest) => {
  const finalProps = Object.assign({}, ...rest);
  return React.createElement(component, finalProps);
};

const propsRoute = ({ component, ...rest }) => (
  <Route
    {...rest}
    render={routeProps => renderMergedProps(component, routeProps, rest)}
  />
);

propsRoute.propTypes = {
  component: PropTypes.element
};

export default propsRoute;
```

Example usage:

```
<PropsRoute
   exact
   path="/blog"
   component={Blog}
   location={location}
   selectBlog={this.selectBlog}
   blogPosts={blogPosts}
 />
```

Comment: cheers, that does the job, not sure why my code doesn't... anyway